# Cannot create a sprite using a RenderTexture

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm making a game, and I have created a class to store the map. I have a function to create a single sprite on which is drawn all the visible map. I've used a RenderTexture and then I create and return a sprite created with it. However, the sprite is completely white.

Here is the code for the map generation and the sprite draw

```
void Map::procedural_generate()
{
    cout << "Starting the map generation" << endl;
    int generation_max = m_size.x * m_size.y, 
        current_generation = 0;
    vector<Decor> decor_vector;
    m_decor_vector.clear();

    const vector<Decor> const_vector
    {
        Decor(GRASS)
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < m_size.x; i++)
    {
        decor_vector.clear();

        for (int j = 0; j < m_size.y; j++)
        {
            decor_vector.push_back(const_vector[GRASS]);
            decor_vector[j].set_position(Vector2f(i * 32, j * 32));
            current_generation++;
            cout << "Generation : " << current_generation << '/' << generation_max << '\r';
        }

        m_decor_vector.push_back(decor_vector);
        decor_vector.clear();
    }
    cout << "Map generation has ended" << endl;
}

Sprite Map::sprite()
{
    RenderTexture map;
    if (!map.create(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGTH))
        cout << "Map : Unable to create the RenderTexture" << endl;

    map.clear(Color::Green);

    for (int i = 0; i < m_size.x; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < m_size.y; j++)
            map.draw(m_decor_vector[i][j].sprite());

    map.display();

    Sprite sprite(map.getTexture());
    return sprite; 
}
```

The problem seems to come from the map.draw part, as, if I use `map.clear(Color::Red)` before the double loop, the sprite stays white, but if I use `sprite.setColor(Color::Red)`, it works. The fact is that the decor sprites are not covering the whole texture (the texture is 1920x1080, and the sprites 320x320), so I can't understand what's happening.

This is not the decor sprite loading, if I use `map.draw(Decor(GRASS))` the sprite is displayed correctly.

I've tried to use pointer for `const_vector` and for the returned sprite, whithout success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Popular mistake when using SFML.

```
Sprite Map::sprite()
{
    RenderTexture map;
    // ...
    Sprite sprite(map.getTexture());
    return sprite; 
}
```

`map` is local. When function ends, `map` is destroyed. Sprite takes texture of `map` as shallow copy, it is only pointer to texture, according to [official tutorial/documentation](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/graphics-sprite.php):

> **The white square problem** 
>   You successfully loaded a texture, constructed a sprite correctly, and... all you see on your screen now
>   is a white square. What happened?
>
> This is a common mistake. When you set the texture of a sprite, all it
>   does internally is store a pointer to the texture instance. Therefore,
>   if the texture is destroyed or moves elsewhere in memory, the sprite
>   ends up with an invalid texture pointer.

So, sprite returned by copy stores dangling pointer. It is just undefined behaviour.

---

[Related (my) answer, posted 1 day ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60548077/how-to-use-a-manager-class-to-manage-characters-and-their-animations-in-c-usin/60549310#60549310)

---

Solution: you have to wrap sprites with textures in some kind of deep-copy-able class.
You cannot rely on shallow defaulted generated copy operations.

---

Such a class could look like:

```
class TexturedSprite {
public:
    sf::Sprite sprite;
    sf::Texture texture;

    TexturedSprite() {
        init(); // load texture
    }

    void init() {
        // load texture
        texture.loadFromFile("texture1.png");
        sprite.setTexture(texture);
        sprite.setPosition(0,0);
    }

    TexturedSprite(const TexturedSprite& theOther) {
        texture = theOther.texture; // deep copy
        sprite.setTexture(texture);
    }

    TexturedSprite& operator=(const TexturedSprite& theOther) {
        if (this == &theOther)
            return *this;
        texture = theOther.texture; // deep copy
        sprite.setTexture(texture);
        return *this;
    }
};
```

then the code:

```
TexturedSprite fooMain;
{
    TexturedSprite foo;     // local 
    fooMain = foo;    
} // foo is destroyed, but = did deep copy of texture
```

is safe.

Comment: It works perfectly, I just had to add some functions and variables to store the position and the texture rectangle