# Why l need to set Texture again in main function?

Tags: c++, textures, sprite, sfml

My code actually works fine but if erase this " **all_e[0].sprite.setTexture(all_e[0].texture);**" code then sprite disappear but there is a code do same stuff in my create entity function which is "**e.sprite.setTexture(e.texture);**"

Like I said before it works fine but I can't understand why I need to call setTexture again.

'''

```
//my function to create entity.

Entity create_entity(std::string filename){
  //create an entity to return.
  Entity e;
  //Setting both texture and sprite.  -Bitmask for background.
  e.image.loadFromFile(filename);               
  e.image.createMaskFromColor(sf::Color(255,255,255,255));
  e.texture.loadFromImage(e.image);
  e.sprite.setTexture(e.texture); 

  //Furter details. Not so important
  e.sprite.scale(4,4);
  e.id = "Hero";
  e.sprite.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(7,0,50,60));
  e.debug_rect.setOutlineColor(sf::Color::Red);
  e.debug_rect.setFillColor(sf::Color(0,0,0,0));
  e.debug_rect.setSize(sf::Vector2f(47,60));
  e.debug_rect.setScale(4,4);
  e.debug_rect.setOutlineThickness(1);
  e.sprite.move(100,100);
  e.debug_rect.setPosition(e.sprite.getPosition());


  return e;
}
```

'''

```
 void game(){
   .
   .//code
   .
   //Use the create_entity to create entity
   all_e.push_back(create_entity("Sprites/hero.png"));
   all_e[0].sprite.setTexture(all_e[0].texture); // !!!!! Why I need to setTexture again here???

   .
   .
   .//code
   .
 }
```

Comment: What's `Entity`? SFML has no such class. Is that something you wrote?

Comment: Read *The white square problem* from [official tutorials](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/graphics-sprite.php). In short, Sprite makes shallow copy of texture - only pointer is copied, not the whole texture.

Comment: I define Entity classs  yess

Comment: rafix07 l get it now thanks. But how can l solve the problem?

Comment: @yusufkılıç Look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60572375/cannot-create-a-sprite-using-a-rendertexture/60572499#60572499). Provide user-defined copy operations for `Entity` class.